# Identity.IsAuthenticated returning false after SignInAsync() in HTTPGET controllers

Tags: asp.net-core

This application should automatically sign-in users using their Environment.Username, but I'm struggling to do it.

In the following HomeController, the variable "ThisGivesNegative" remains false even after the "HttpContext.SignInAsync" is invoked. 
When I put this code in an HTTPPost action, the sign in is correct so I guess there has to be something with the configuration but after navigating in the web none of the StackOverflow posts worked.

Could any of you give me a hand? Thanks!

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAppUserService _appUserService;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public HomeController(
            ApplicationDbContext context,
            IAppUserService appUserService,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory
            )
        {
            _context = context;
            _appUserService = appUserService;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AccountController>();
        }
       public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            string WindowsUsername = Environment.UserName;
            if (WindowsUsername != null)
            {
                List<AppRole> RolesForThisUser = new List<AppRole>();
                RolesForThisUser = _context.AppUserAppRoles.Where(x => x.AppUser.ApexID == WindowsUsername).Select(x => x.AppRole).ToList();

                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    //AllowRefresh = false,
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
                };

                List<Claim> MyClaims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, WindowsUsername),
                    };
                foreach (AppRole ThisRole in RolesForThisUser)
                {
                    MyClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, ThisRole.RoleName.ToString()));
                }

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(MyClaims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, properties);               
                bool ThisGivesNegative = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Here my ConfigureServices code:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
                .Configure<API_IP21_CurrentValues>(ConfigAppSettings.GetSection("API_IP21_CurrentValues"))
                .Configure<API_IP21_HistoricValues>(ConfigAppSettings.GetSection("API_IP21_HistoricValues"))
                .Configure<API_PPM_DailyValues>(ConfigAppSettings.GetSection("API_PPM_DailyValues"))
                .Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                })
                .AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(ConfigAppSettings.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value);
                })
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Views/Home/Index.cshtml";
                    options.LogoutPath = "/Views/Home/Index.cshtml";
                });
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>()
                .AddTransient<IAppUserService, AppUserService>()
                .AddTransient<IEquipmentRepository, EquipmentRepository>()
                .AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }
```

Comment: [`Environment.UserName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=netcore-2.2) will **always** refer to the **same user** which is the one that is running your server application. You will not be able to use that to determine the client’s user name. That simply doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, here some help for those in need! 
    Esentially, cookies are read before the Home Controller is fired so when the view is rendered, the program doesn't know this user has those cookies. We need to reload. 
    I solve this by adding the following code just before "return view()" in the Home Controller.

```
            if (FirstPostback == false)
            {
                RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { FirstPostback = true});
            }

            return View(new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
```